# How to remove Esri basemap credits?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online-basemaps

As you can see from the attached sample map, the Esri basemap credits are overpowering and reduce the cartographic design of the entire map.  These credits appear to be new to 10.1 and essentially make these maps unusable in any sort of publication.

Is there a way to remove the credits?

[image]

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Go to View -> Layout, then go to Insert -> Dynamic Text -> Service Layer Credits.

You should then be able to move the credits to wherever you want. (Or completely remove them)

Comment: That did the trick.  However, I have to move the dynamic credits outside of the print margins for it to work.  It seems that whenever I delete the dynamic text, it converts back to static credits.

Comment: If you make the text box very small it will stop showing the text and prevent them from returning after being deleted.  I usually make the box about a 1/4 inch square and then put it in part of the legend.

Comment: You can also set label color to `No color`, I think is the easiest way

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to change the text color to "No Color", instead of moving the text box off the preview pane. This is useful when performing a graphic export and selecting the "Clip Output to Graphics Extent". Otherwise, the text box located off the preview pane will be included in the export.

Answer (score 10):

I made a video on how to do it at [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ0pMKq7bB4&feature=share&list=UUSem8OyZXv0PSl4x6zy7_7Q)

Go to View -> Layout, then go to Insert -> Dynamic Text -> Service Layer Credits.

You should then be able to move the credits to wherever you want.  You can't delete it.  If you do it will come back.  So you need to move it off the preview pane.

Answer (score 7):

After you make it dynamic text, send it to the back (right-click the text element, click Order > Send to Back). It will be behind the rest of your layout, so it won't show up in any exported or printed maps.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the DRAW toolbox and create a box and draw it over the credits. That is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Insert" tab, go to the "Graphics and Text" group, click the "Dynamic Text" down arrow, scroll to "Layout" category, click "Service Layer Credits", under "Options" uncheck "Visible".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcGIS Pro, to hide the service layer credits you should follow these steps: Insert -> Dynamic Text -> "Layout Section" -> Service Layer Credits. Since your intent is to hide these credits, I would recommend drawing the textbox outside of your layout frame.

Do note that if you create an inset map on the same layout page, you may have to follow these steps again for that map frames service layer credits.