# Modify Service Layer Credits in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

Is there a way to modify (edit, move, resize, delete) Service Layer credits in ArcGIS Pro?

From [How to remove Esri basemap credits?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41153) I know that it is possible in ArcMap but I could not find a way to do it in ArcGIS Pro.

The default placement is often sub-optimal and modification would alleviate most issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure is essentially the same for ArcGIS Pro as it is/was in ArcMap.

You need to add the service credits as dynamic text, you can then update or move them.

- After adding your layout
- From the **Insert Menu** choose **Dynamic Text** (under the Text section)
- Scroll down to the Layout section and click **Service Layer Credits**

This will allow you to draw a box somewhere in the layout. You can edit the credits from this box.