# Removing duplicate service layer credits when using an inset map

Tags: arcgis-pro, dynamic-text, inset-map

Using ArcGIS Pro, after adding an inset map, using the same basemap (Oceans), I noticed that several service layer credits were duplicated.
[image: screenshot of service layer credits for both primary map and inset map]

Removing the inset removes the duplicates.

[image: screenshot of service layer credits for just basemap]

Removing the inset isn't a solution--it just confirms that the dynamic text for the inset map gets appended, even if it duplicates the credits for another map already on the layout. [Edit: In updating the post in response to comments, I notice that the smaller scale inset map has one additional credit, so it's not an exact duplicate.]

I understand how to hide all the credits, but I would prefer not to do that.  My course's professor won't penalize for the duplicates, but they sure will penalize hiding the credits!

Comment: You might indicate the software you are using.

Comment: Adding a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347072/modify-service-layer-credits-in-arcgis-pro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify Service Layer Credits in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347072/modify-service-layer-credits-in-arcgis-pro)

Comment: @john  thanks, that thread does help with managing service level credits.  Unfortunately, it doesn't help with editing the contents of the dynamic text itself.